# SQL join five tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am working on issue, and cannot resolve it.

I have five tables:

```
    t_employee = {employee_id_pk, fullname, phone, position, passport}

    t_facility = {facility_id_pk, direction, title}

    t_employee_facility = {emp_fac_id_pk, employee_id_fk, facility_id_fk}  

    this table is @ManyToMany relationship
    between 't_employee' and 't_facility'

    t_transport = {transport_id_pk, type}

    t_trip = {trip_id_pk, trip_code, employee_id_fk, transport_id_fk}

    this table is @ManyToMany relationship between 't_employee' and 't_transport'
```

And I want to get unique rows
I tried something like this

```
SELECT
  employee_id, fullname, passport, phone, position, direction, title,
  trip_code
FROM
  t_facility
  INNER JOIN t_employee_facility USING (facility_id)
  INNER JOIN t_employee USING (employee_id)
  INNER JOIN t_trip USING (employee_id)
GROUP BY
  employee_id,
  facility_id,
  trip_code
```

There are 8 uniquie rows.
But the above example gives me 18, when I remove `trip_id` I get 8 rows, but
in this case I get repeating `trip_code` values  for each employee_id.

I want to extract only not repeating rows. I guess that, I should do it using `INNER JOIN`, but I'm not sure.

Is it possible to join all this tables ?

thank you

Regards

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem that you are having. Does your query work?

Comment: My query doesn't work.For example, I have 5 unique rows, but this query (in problem description) retrieves 8 rows. I'm sorry, but I'm not very strong in big join with five tables.

Comment: I also can attach screenshot if it helps you to figure out, what I want))

Comment: It would help to have the correct names of the columns in all the table. For example, what is facility_id? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Can there be more than one facility for an employee? Can there be more than one trip for an employee? If yes, that's why you get more rows from your query than there are employees. Question is, which single facility or trip do you actually want from the multiple possible for an employee?

Comment: thank you, for your comments, I will edit my description. I'm going to provide more information.

Comment: trip_id is probably an identity column so of course you would get more depending on the data set. Even group by tries to group them since trip_id is there, it simply wont be able to.

Comment: I think that I understand now) thank you, but can I somehow write needed query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved using nested join query as follow:

```
SELECT B.employee_id, employee_id, fullname, passport, phone,
  position,direction, title, trip_code 
FROM (SELECT A.employee_id, employee_id, fullname, passport, phone,
  position,direction, title  
FROM (SELECT employee_id, direction, title FROM t_facility 
       JOIN t_employee_facility 
         ON t_facility.facility_id = t_employee_facility.facility_id
     ) AS A 
     JOIN employee ON A.employee_id = employee.employee_id) AS B 
JOIN t_trip ON B.employee_id = t_trip.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

the INNER JOIN keyword selects should have matching values in both tables.
Ex :

```
SELECT id_pk,information,about
FROM information
INNER JOIN employe ON information.id_pk= employe.id_employe;
```

So yes, you can join your table when declare it each table.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the rows to be unique but it is OK, that some employees show more than one facility or trip, you may use the `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       employee_id,
       fullname,
       passport,
       phone,
       position,
       direction,
       title,
       trip_code
       FROM t_facility
            INNER JOIN t_employee_facility
                       USING (facility_id)
            INNER JOIN t_employee
                       USING (employee_id)
            INNER JOIN t_trip
                       USING (employee_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many unclear things in your question, still I'm posting whatever I have figured-out.

First of all I cannot see the table `t_employee` in `FROM` clause so I'm not sure this query will work. To get the column values for `fullname, passport, phone, position` you need to add the relevant table `t_employee` into `FROM` clause.

I'm not pretty sure about the `JOIN` syntax, you can check the MySQL JOINs syntax [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php).

```
SELECT
  employee_id, fullname, passport, phone, position, direction, title,
  trip_code
FROM
  t_employee
  INNER JOIN t_facility USING (facility_id)
  INNER JOIN t_employee_facility USING (facility_id)
  INNER JOIN t_employee USING (employee_id)
  INNER JOIN t_trip USING (employee_id)
GROUP BY
  employee_id,
  facility_id,
  trip_code
```

If this still doesn't work, you can try doing `SELECT DISTINCT` to get unique records, see the syntax [here](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_distinct.asp.html).